# Version Control WordPress Website with themes installed

Tags: php, wordpress, version-control, mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

Being new to Wordpress development ecosystem have few queries which I m stumbled upon currently. 
Have installed wordpress and it was working as expected. Had installed a theme to the website recently to the local working copy. Also, added 2 more members to the team which was previously single person and thus made the code version controlled with bitbucket server repository.

Now, the issue is when the new developers cloned the remote repository to their local machine ( entire wordpress with installed theme ) is available. But its not working properly as the new pages/links/menus/images added are not reflecting for the other's local .

Would like to know the general thumbrules which needs to be followed while version controlling Wordpress. Is the added themes/additional code changed files etc. only need to be version controlled instead of the whole Wordpress files? In my scenario what would be the changes I need to do ( any files which I need to configure to get the latest repository code to run locally )
Would we need to version control the Wordpress including the Database?
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the main issue you have there is all the things you want are within the database. There are version control things for db but not sure how best they work... so you either export and share you db with them, or all work off a remote db from a server. You can change db credentials, including ip address etc in wp-config.

As for version control, I only save my theme in git and the wp-config etc etc... the bare minimum I can. Then I use composer https://getcomposer.org/ to pull in wordpress and make use of https://wpackagist.org/ to get plugins.

Roots did a nice introduction to composer and WordPress - where I started learning from and is worth a look: https://roots.io/using-composer-with-wordpress/

Comment: was really such a valuable information. Thanks @Simon

Comment: So basically I should install wordpress in every developers machine locally and then add only the theme installed into the repository ( version control) . and use a central db? i was looking for any option available to use local DB for each developers any workaround . Would appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: If the db is local... then its local to that machine, and you can't track changes. The db is not something you can add to git etc... I tend to have a "staging environment" where any major changes are made - and users get a copy of that when needed so that their local copy is up to date.

Comment: thanks alot.. now i m getting a much better idea on it.

Comment: The main thing for me is composer - even if you only use it for WordPress - its maddening adding WordPress to your git repo :) and it makes its super easy to update. Hope you get on ok with everything.

Comment: One more thing would like to know to get it as a whole. How would one go to export the Local DB to share? is there any tool to do this without much effort?

Comment: Not particularly... the easiest is just to use PHPMyAdmin or similar and do an export - zip it up (or use tools within your db management tool) and share with colleagues via dropbox or similar.